# How to add an integer to an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This must be quite basic, but I was wondering how to add an integer to an array?

I know I can add strings like this:

```
NSMutableArray *trArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[trArray addObject:@"0"];
[trArray addObject:@"1"];
[trArray addObject:@"2"];
[trArray addObject:@"3"];
```

But I guess I can't simply add integers like so:

```
NSMutableArray *trArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[trArray addObject:0];
[trArray addObject:1];
[trArray addObject:2];
[trArray addObject:3];
```

At least the compiler isn't happy with that and tells me that I'm doing a cast without having told it so.

Any explanations would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes that's right. The compiler won't accept your code like this. The difference is the following:

If you write `@"a String"`, it's the same as if you created a string and autoreleased it. So you create an object by using `@"a String"`.

But an array can only store objects (more precise: pointers to object). So you have to create objects which store your integer.

```
NSNumber *anumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];
[yourArray addObject:anumber];
```

To retrive the integer again, do it like this

```
NSNumber anumber = [yourArray objectAtIndex:6];
int yourInteger = [anumber intValue];
```

I hope my answer helps you to understand why it doesn't work. You can't cast an integer to a pointer. And that is the warning you get from Xcode.

**EDIT:**

It is now also possible to write the following

```
[yourArray addObject:@3];
```

which is a shortcut to create a NSNumber. The same syntax is available for arrays

```
@[@1, @2];
```

will give you an NSArray containing 2 NSNumber objects with the values 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand this now. Your explanation is very good!

Comment: Thank you. The answer of mservidio is absolutly correct. But I always like to have an explanation. ;-)

Comment: Just a follow-up question: Is 'number' stored in my array an integer (int) or an NSInteger? Or doesn't this really matter?

Comment: As far as I know the difference is only a difference in the size which is used to store that value. I normally use int. The only reason for me: it's less to write. ;-) Perhaps there's someone around here who can explain the differnce. I can't.

Comment: This is wrong, string literals aren't autoreleased. They have static storage duration and the highest possible reference count (which indicates that their refcount can't even be decreased by `release`).

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. Where do you have that information from? I would like to read more about it.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use NSNumbers I think, try adding these objects to your array: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myInt];

```
NSMutableArray *trArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     
NSNumber *yourNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] numberWithInt:5];

[trArray addObject: yourNumber];
```

Comment: mservidio is correct. I believe the way to think of this is because `@"2"` is a `NSString` object. However `2` by itself is a value, not an object.

Comment: to expand, you basically create an instance of the NSNumber object that is a object version of the primitive int or whatever and then adds this object to the array. 

Also, to get the primitive value back out of the array, use [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this if you want to use strings:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1]];
[[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```